# How to achieve no gaps between triangles in software renderer like in Quake?

Tags: graphics, c, rasterization, fixed-point

I've heard alot that I need to use fixed-point math, top-left rule, etc. to eliminate gaps between triangles but the thing is how did Quake not have any gaps, did it? I've seen Quake's math file and vec2, vec3 were only typedefs for a float array, so I don't really understand how Quake hadn't any 'stitches'. Was the game doing a pixel overfill?

Also, I heard that Quake was an example of a gapless rasterizer but that might be rumors. Haven't seen gaps myself, actually.

Comment: What would prevent Quake from using the top-left rule as you've identified in your research? That should close all the gaps outside of fairly rare edge cases in float rounding errors, which might just not come up for their triangle arrangements.

Comment: @DMGregory, maybe it did use but I didn't notice in code or could miss something.

Answer (score 0):

Using floating point 3D coordinates isn't an issue because the gaps only show up after converting to integer pixel coordinates, which you need for rendering them on screen. It's at that point that you need to be careful how you define which pixels are inside a triangle.

If you look at the source code for Quake, you can see that they are using integers. Here's what I found with a quick search:

https://github.com/id-Software/Quake/blob/bf4ac424ce754894ac8f1dae6a3981954bc9852d/WinQuake/d_iface.h#L66

https://github.com/id-Software/Quake/blob/bf4ac424ce754894ac8f1dae6a3981954bc9852d/WinQuake/d_polyse.c#L150

Note that all standard 3D rendering APIs have similar rules for determining which pixels are considered inside each triangle. Here are the D3D9 ones, for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/rasterization-rules

Comment: Thanks for the resources! But integer vertices were somehow turned from float to int. So I still don't really understand how Quake managed to do this conversion correctly, sorry. But thanks for the answer!

Comment: How you convert from float to int doesn't make any difference, as long as it's consistent (i.e. the same floating point vertex position always ends up as the same integer pixel coordinate).

Comment: Note that there are other ways to get gaps between triangles in a mesh that aren't related to the triangle fill rules (e.g. https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1461/why-do-t-junctions-in-meshes-result-in-cracks).

Comment: In my software rasterizer I get different results when converting simply casting from float to int and casting with 0.5 bias for each vertex coordinate but always end up having an overfill or gaps. Your idea is absolutely correct and I agree with it but surprisingly the outcome is always illogical and gaps appear differently. Just in case, the models I use are all double-checked and the absence of T-junctions is guaranteed.